# Search for emails from contacts with multiple email addresses

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

At my current company, all employees have *.com and *.de email addresses. The problem now is that if I search for emails from a certain contact I have to choose between emails from either one of the two. Is there a way to be able to search for both of them at once?

Answer (score 5):

You could write directly the search terms as was suggested in the Alex answer but also Gmail could write if for you.

> from:(johndoe@example.com OR johndoe@example.de)

OR

```
from:(johndoe@example.com | johndoe@example.de)
```

In Gmail, hover over the email in a message received by the contact that you want to search for all the emails sent by that contact, a contact card popup will be displayed, then click on the Messages link at the bottom of the card.

In Google Contacts, open the contact record, click More > View recent conversations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, try this:

```
from:(johndoe@example.com OR johndoe@example.de)
```

Please note that the `OR` operator must be in capital letters.